# How to search through a JSON feed

Tags: python, json, google-maps

I'm using the code below and make a call to the Google Maps API and parse some JSON data.

```
def getLocalityFromPostCode(postcode):
    import urllib, json
    import pprint
    url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%s&sensor=false" % postcode
    googleResponse = urllib.urlopen(url)
    jsonResponse = json.loads(googleResponse.read())
    return jsonResponse
```

This works fine. However, i only need the value from`['results']['address_components']` where the `'type'` is  `[ "locality", "political" ]` however, the index of this value differs depending on how precise the given postcode string is.

If i give a straight poscode (like XX10) the value appears in the 0th item in the `address_components` list. However, if i give a city and postcode it appears in the 1st item.

Can someone help me please. I need to search through address_components for the `[ "locality", "political" ]` value.

EDIT

You can view te feeds at `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=sy4&sensor=false` (just postcode) and `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=47%20High%20Street%20Shrewsbury,%20SY4&sensor=false` (full address).

As you can see in example 1 the data I'm looking for is in index 1, whereas in the second example the data I'm looking for is in index 2.

Comment: Can you post an example of the JSON under each circumstance?

Comment: By the way, using `requests.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {'address': '%s', 'sensor': 'false'}).json()` looks better to me. Especially if You'd use separate variable for attributes. `import requests` is obviously required.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like what you want :)

```
results = json.load(googleResponse)['results']

for result in results:
    for address_component in result['address_components']:
        if address_component['types'] == ['locality', 'political']
            # address_component['long_name'] and
            # address_component['short_name'] are your data
            break
```

The cool thing about [JSON](http://json.org) and [Python dicts](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html) is that you don't need to index by number, you index by name. In this case, your object (or at least the data you care about) breaks down like this:

```
'results': # a list of resulting dicts
[
    { # one of those resulting dicts
        'address_components':  # a key, representing some other data
        [ # which, in this case, is a list of address component dicts
            { # like this
                'long_name': 'A String. The Long Name.'
                'short_name': 'Another String. The Short Name.'
                'types': # a list of type strings
                [
                    'locality', # one of the types
                    'political' # the other type
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: I get an error `TypeError: string indices must be integers` on the line reading `for address_component in result['address_component']:`

Comment: whoops! i neglected to dive into results! fixing now :)

Comment: I got it working now thought. Changed `result['address_component']` to `result['address_components']` and changed `results` to `googleResponse['results']`

Answer (score -2):

Create an object from the json and access the values by the keys

```
import json
obj = json.loads(jsonString)
```

Comment: Ack, no! JSON is *not* a subset of Python, and you wouldn't want to evaluate somebody else's stuff in your application anyway. `json.loads` (as used by the OP) is the correct method to get an object. The question was concerning how to access data from the object itself.